# Rails 3: trigger submit on remote form via js/prototype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs, onsubmit

I'm working on converting and old Rails app from Rails 2.3.14 to Rails 3.0.

It's still using Prototype (converting to jQuery is a later step in our migration path), so no jQuery answers, please.

We've got lots of forms with pulldowns that we currently submit as AJAX whenever one of the pulldowns gets changed.

In the **Rails 2.3** version we used `form_remote_tag` and then the `onchange` event for the pulldowns would call `$('myform').onsubmit();` to submit the form ajaxily.

In the **Rails 3.0** branch, we've converted the form to use `form_tag` with `:remote => true`, however, when we select a option from the pulldown, Firebug reports `$('myform').onsubmit is not a function.`

Changing from `$('myform').onsubmit();` to just `$('myform').submit();` causes the form to get submitted, but  **not ajaxily**.

Any suggestions on how to use the onchange event on the pulldowns to submit the form ajaxily with Prototype and Rails 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I simply removed the `:remote => true` from the `form_tag` call, and added the following argument in it's place...

`:onsubmit => "new Ajax.Request('#{url}', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get', parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;"`

That basically reproduces what the old `form_remote_tag` used to do.

This isn't intended to be a permanent solution.  Just a stepping stone to get us to the point of switching this app over to jQuery.